# How to write these data values in a formula field on crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a SQL statement, but I cannot use it within the report (because it keeps crashing CRXI) so how can I write this within a formula field ?

```
((ACTUAL_DELIVERY - 15 MINUTES < T.DELIVER_BY_END  AND TIME(T.DELIVER_BY_END) <> '00:00:00') OR
(ACTUAL_DELIVERY - 15 MINUTES <= T.DELIVER_BY_END + 1 DAY))
```

if the records satisfy these values `then 1 else 0`

Comment: They are all Timestamp values.

Comment: how are you writing these in crystal?

Comment: HI @Siva i posted the answer, I used it as a formula field to calculate a value.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF ({TLORDER.DELIVER_BY_END} - {TLORDER.ACTUAL_DELIVERY} >= -.0104 AND 
{TLORDER.DELIVER_BY_END} <> DATETIME(YEAR({TLORDER.DELIVER_BY_END}), MONTH({TLORDER.DELIVER_BY_END}), DAY({TLORDER.DELIVER_BY_END}), 00,00,00)) 
OR 
({TLORDER.DELIVER_BY_END} - {TLORDER.ACTUAL_DELIVERY} >= -1.0104 AND 
{TLORDER.DELIVER_BY_END} = DATETIME(YEAR({TLORDER.DELIVER_BY_END}), MONTH({TLORDER.DELIVER_BY_END}), DAY({TLORDER.DELIVER_BY_END}), 00,00,00))
THEN 1 ELSE 0
```